# Parametric curves in maple

Tags: maple

I know how to plot a parametric curve in Maple (18), but is it also possible to 'define' the parametric equation? I.e. I have to find the intersection of: 
f:= t-> sin(t);
g:= t -> 0.5*sin(2*t);
and y := x -> x/2

Comment: you can parameterize the equation $y=x^2$

Answer (score 1):

First, change **g** to **g:= t-> sin(2*t)/2;** don't use decimal points in Maple code when you can use the exact fraction. Then, to get the points of intersection, use

```
([f,g])~({solve(g(t)=y(f(t)))});
```